# jQuery AJAX Onchange Redirect Issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, events

I have my bit of jQuery AJAX code, to send a file to a PHP script, update/insert to db and continue to edit by ID as redirect. Works fine.

Problem is.. every other page except homepage (no rewrites, base url) the script will break the onchange event listener, and skip upload then continue to editing a broken upload.

Every other page, this code works perfect and does as intended. But homepage, it does not listen. I can not figure it out. Only recently we got the last insert ID working for redirect to edit entry.

```
$(document).ready(function(a) {
    $("#form-fileUpload").on("change", function(a) {
    var file_data = $('#uploadFile').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    alert(form_data);                             
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax_file_upload.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,                         
        type: 'post',
        success: function(php_script_response){
        if (data.redirect == true) {
            window.location.href = '/file-edit.php?id=<?php echo mysql_insert_id(); ?>';
        }
            //alert(php_script_response);
        }
     });
    });
});
```

How can I prevent this from ignoring the onchange submit action for our form? Is this a root domain thing? Didn't think the PHP code was relevant, it works fine as intended.

So user browses for file, and form automatically uploads and redirect happens sending them to edit and add more details in a form. Perfect on all pages but homepage. Is the JS at fault? Is there handling for this in this situation away from sub pages?

The PHP code that plays this role (AJAX script):

```
$id = $conn->lastInsertId();
// Redirect & complete details
header("Location: https://www.website.com/editfile?id=".$id.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use full url to direct in jQuery like below

```
window.location.href = 'https://www.website.com/file-edit.php?id=<?php echo mysql_insert_id(); ?>';
```